# How to copy and paste text with its font styling in android?

Tags: java, android

Here is what i have tried.

I used `string="TextView"` and `font family="aguafina_script"`, when i paste the clip it loses its `font family "aguafina_script"` and paste only **TextView**.

```
textView.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            ClipboardManager clipboardManager = (ClipboardManager) getSystemService(Context.CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
            ClipData clipData = ClipData.newPlainText("data",textView.getText());
            clipboardManager.setPrimaryClip(clipData);
});
```

Comment: Your text has no font styling. Your text view has. You copy paste just text. And there is no question in your post. Nor are you telling what you do.

Comment: This might help : https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ClipData.html#implementing-copy-or-drag